# How to declare an inter-type method with return type of every object's class?

Tags: java, aspectj, aop

In my AspectJ project, I have a code like the following:

```
public aspect MyAspect {
    public Object MyInterface.getMyself() {
        return this;
    }
}


public interface MyInterface {
}

public class MyClassOne implements MyInterface {}
public class MyClassTwo implements MyInterface {}
```

So, how does AspectJ inject the code within the inter-type declarations? Also, is there a way of, instead of declaring `MyInterface.getMyself()`'s as `Object`, declare as `this.getClass()` or anything like that, i.e., injecting `MyClassOne` and `MyClassTwo` where applicable?

Comment: so you want to return an instance of either MyClassOne or MyClassTwo in getMyself()?

Comment: Well, yes... As I wrote, I don't know how the code injection works, but my goal is to return an instance of `MyClassOne` when `getMyself()` is called from an instance of `MyClassOne` and of `MyClassTwo` when called from an instance of that class.

Comment: PS: I know that I could return a generic type (`<T> T ...`), but this isn't exactly what I wanted.

Comment: No way to do this without generics or by creating a new ITD for each implementing class.  I can code up for you a generics solution, which I think would be nice and elegant.

Comment: @Andrew, I'm all up for suggestions. :) BTW, what's an ITD?

Comment: An ITD is an intertype declaration, which is what you are doing above.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry. :) Can you post the generics solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
aspect MyAspect {
    public S MyInterface<S>.getMyself() {
        return (S) this;
    }  
}

interface MyInterface<T extends MyInterface<T>> {
}

class MyClassOne implements MyInterface<MyClassOne> {}
class MyClassTwo implements MyInterface<MyClassTwo> {}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClassOne aClassOne = new MyClassOne().getMyself();
        MyClassTwo aClassTwo = new MyClassTwo().getMyself();
        MyClassOne errorClassOne = new MyClassTwo().getMyself(); // compile error
        MyClassTwo errorClassTwo = new MyClassOne().getMyself(); // compile error
    }
}
```

Fun with generics!  Answer is straight forward, I think, but let me know if this is confusing for you.